# rm refuses to remove folder! (nothing to do with the -R option)

Tags: rm

I'm using Ubuntu on my personal laptop, and on my system, whenever I use `rm` on a file, it is gone. for good.
The problem is on my university server.
I am trying to delete a folder: environment/tests from my home directory.
To my big surprise, when I use rm environment/tests (for some strange reason, rm does not require the -R option in order to delete a folder on the university server...), this is what I get:

```
u2 **** 114 : rm environment/tests
/bin/mv: cannot move `environment/tests/' to `/u/stud/****/../TrashCan/****/tests': File exists
u2 **** 115 :
```

(the **** are replacement for my username)

So I tried to remove it from the Trash can, but realized it's a recursive call... :)

```
u2 **** 157 : rm ~/../TrashCan/****/tests
/bin/mv: `/u/stud/****/../TrashCan/****/tests' and `/u/stud/****/../TrashCan/****/tests' are the same file
u2 **** 158 :
```

First of all, what does mv has to do here? (notice it is a /bin/mv error)
Second, how can I delete this folder once and for all?
In fact, while I'm at it, I'd like to completely empty the TrashCan.
But again, this:

```
u2 **** 169 : rm * ~/../TrashCan/
```

Does not work.
The server runs the following version:

```
u2 **** 170 : uname -a
Linux u2 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 28 21:11:36 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
u2 **** 171 :
```

Comment: Can you please check the value of `alias rm`?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Just execute the command `alias rm` to see if `rm` has been aliased on your system.

Comment: Most likely `rm` is superseded by `mv * /wherever/TrashCan/$USER/` to allow quick data recovery as some students seemingly had accidentally removed essential files. Check `alias rm` and if nothing strange shows up `whereis rm` and then read the file to which this points you.

Comment: Aw! Yes it has been aliased! 
`/bin/mv -f !* /u/stud/****/../TrashCan/****`
That explains the mv! Now, how can I use the original rm (I want to keep the alias though)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `rm` as been aliased to `/bin/mv -f !* /u/stud/****/../TrashCan/****`.

Prefix the aliased command  with `\` to disable the alias:

`\rm`, will run the original `rm` command.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that someone has created an alias for **rm** command (probably replaced it by **mv** command) on the system.

You can check by executing:

```
alias rm
```

You can reset it to default by:

```
alias rm="rm -v"
```

Comment: You can reset it to the default with a simple `unalias rm`

Comment: [Or run bash built-in `command rm ...`](https://askubuntu.com/a/538818/349837)